# How to export KonvaJS canvas to PDF file including images?

Tags: konvajs

I'm using [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to export my KonvaJS stage to a PDF file. It's working fine until I try to add an image.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
var pdfGenerator = new jsPDF();
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    var konvaImage = new Konva.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: imageObj
    });

    layer.add(konvaImage);
    stage.add(layerPDF);
    layer.draw();

    var dataURL = stagePDF.toDataURL({pixelRatio: 2});
    pdfGenerator.addImage(dataURL, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 189, 267);

    pdfGenerator.save('stage.pdf');
};
imageObj.src = 'absolute-path-to-image.png';
```

When I try it I get this error:

```
jspdf.min.js:50 Uncaught Error: Supplied data is not a JPEG
    at jspdf.min.js:50
    at Object.x.processJPEG (jspdf.min.js:50)
    at Object.x.addImage (jspdf.min.js:50)
    at Image.imageObj.onload (a9ad15f30fefd32778:468)
```

Any ideas of what can be the problem? If I use only KonvaJS shapes like Rect and Circle it works.

Answer (score 1):

By default `node.toDataURL()` generate base64 for png image. As I can see from your message you need to provide a jpg image. You can use this:

```
var dataURL = stagePDF.toDataURL({
  pixelRatio: 2,
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
});
pdfGenerator.addImage(dataURL, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 189, 267);
```

Comment: I tried this, but error still persists. I just realized that when I call the `node.toDataURL()` I get this error message: `Konva warning: Unable to get data URL. Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`.
Maybe it's because of the image hosted on another server? (Image hosted on Amazon S3).

Comment: It was a cross-origin issue. I just posted my solution. Thanks for your response! It helped me to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I added `imageObj.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";` before `imageObj.src = 'absolute-path-to-image.png';` and that fixed it. It was a cross-origin issue, not related with KonvaJS.